# R: rename hierarchy levels of an hts object

Tags: r

How can I rename the levels an hts (hierarchical and grouped time series) object created with the hts [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hts/hts.pdf)?

Example:

```
abc <- ts(5 + matrix(sort(rnorm(200)), ncol = 4, nrow = 100))
x <- hts(abc, c(1,1,2,2))
```

The hts object `x` has 3 levels (incl. total) hierachically assigned by `c(1,1,2,2)`.
When using `plot(x, levels=2)` I just get the plot for level 1 (2nd in hierarchy) with lines named A and B.

How can I rename those levels with custom names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The names are hard-coded.

But the package is being re-built from scratch for the next version, so I'll add this as a feature request.

Comment: Thanks Rob, the new version works very good. The new naming mechanism is very smart, although it took me a while to understand.